# Is it possible to extract the files like app.py from a Docker Image saved on Artifactory?

Tags: docker, artifactory

After a company Windows 10 upgrade I can't access my VM which has files on it needed for a deployment. I am wondering if there is a way I can get the actual files like app.py after pulling the image locally. Its stored on Artifactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `docker cp` to do that.
E.g., to copy `/etc/hosts` from a running container named `foo` to the local directory, you'd run `docker cp foo:/etc/hosts .`

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: thank you for the help! I know its probably been asked on here before but I was having a hard time searching for it online since the words I was using to describe the issue are other Docker commands (like extract).